# jboss 7 - get module name for session bean

Tags: java, ejb, jboss7.x, jndi

*Jboss 7*

**Description**

In order to get reference to some component (session bean in this example) we can use *lookup* function. If component is not in the same module we have to specify module name.

Example:

```java
String moduleName = "exampleModuleName";  
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
IHelloLocal helloBean = (IHelloLocal) context.lookup("java:app/" + moduleName + "/" + HelloBean.class.getSimpleName() + "!" + IHelloLocal.class.getName());
```

The problem here is hard coded module name.

It is acceptable when module name is always the same. But it can change in time. For example default jar name contains version, when module is built using maven. It is ok to have version in the name of jar file, but this forces us to find every place in code where module name is hard coded. This is a terrible thing.

**Question**

How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<module-name>` in ejb-jar.xml to use a static module name rather than having it default to the archive base name.

Answer (score 0):

The `maven-ear-plugin` supports a [file name mapping](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customize-file-name-mapping.html) named `no-version-for-ejbs` which removes the version from EJB-JARs in an EAR.